# Animate height onclick of inline div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-float

This might seem as a very basic question but I got stuck while animating the height of the `div`.There are multiple div with css `float:left`.When I `click` the particular div its height should increase.But since its height is increasing all the other div's position is also changing.I dont want them to change their position.What I want is that the div just below the `target` div should move down without affecting the other div's.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6md9wrxL/)

Here is the code.

```js
$("div").click(function() {
  if ($(this).height() != 100)
    $(this).animate({
      height: 100
    }, 1000);
  else
    $(this).animate({
      height: 150
    }, 1000);
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  HELLO WORLD 1
</div>
<div>
  HELLO WORLD 2
</div>
<div>
  HELLO WORLD 3
</div>
<div>
  HELLO WORLD 4
</div>
<div>
  HELLO WORLD 5
</div>
<div>
  HELLO WORLD 6
</div>
<div>
  HELLO WORLD 7
</div>
<div>
  HELLO WORLD 8
</div>
<div>
  HELLO WORLD 9
</div>
<div>
  HELLO WORLD 10
</div>
```

Comment: i saw , will be as you tell from using floats, better in html group content by column inyto a one div for one column

Answer (score 1):

I think that exactly this what do you expect is barely possible, but if it is, it may be very hard to achieve. But if you would use `flexbox` with some `jQuery` and `css` transition, you will get fully responsive scheme, on every screen size.

**[Jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/4b4hf5dd/)**

```js
$(".container").find('div').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('show');
});
```

```css
.container div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid;
  margin: 10px;
  transition: .5s ease height;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.show {
  height: 150px !important;
  transition: .5s ease height;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <div>
    HELLO WORLD 1
  </div>
  <div>
    HELLO WORLD 2
  </div>
  <div>
    HELLO WORLD 3
  </div>
  <div>
    HELLO WORLD 4
  </div>
  <div>
    HELLO WORLD 5
  </div>
  <div>
    HELLO WORLD 6
  </div>
  <div>
    HELLO WORLD 7
  </div>
  <div>
    HELLO WORLD 8
  </div>
  <div>
    HELLO WORLD 9
  </div>
  <div>
    HELLO WORLD 10
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is almost similar but the problem is all the below divs are moving not just the div below the target div.

Comment: @shubhamagrawal I know my friend, but as I said above it will be very hard to achieve, because script will have to check somehow which divs are exactly under him, and it bet that it will be static method without possibility to work with the full responsible web design. Try to shrunk the window to the max and it will still work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and now I have even understood that it is not that easy to achieve but the problem is that it is the project requirement and I have to do as per the instructions given to me.I am also looking for any alternatives to do this.

Comment: @shubhamagrawal I wish I could help you. I will try to improve it, if I will achieve anything better, I will let you know (:

Comment: Ok thank you for your help even I am working on it.Hope I get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I guess you could do it by adding another div inside, and extend that div's size instead:

```js
$(".inner-div").click(function() {
  if ($(this).height() != 100)
    $(this).animate({
      height: 100
    }, 1000);
  else
    $(this).animate({
      height: 150
    }, 1000);
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.outter-div{
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: visible;
}

.inner-div{
  border: 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outter-div">
  <div class="inner-div">
  HELLO WORLD 1
  </div>
</div>
<div class="outter-div">
  <div class="inner-div">
  HELLO WORLD 2
  </div>
</div>
<div class="outter-div">
  <div class="inner-div">
  HELLO WORLD 3
  </div>
</div>
<div class="outter-div">
  <div class="inner-div">
  HELLO WORLD 4
  </div>
</div>
<div class="outter-div">
  <div class="inner-div">
  HELLO WORLD 5
  </div>
</div>
<div class="outter-div">
  <div class="inner-div">
  HELLO WORLD 6
  </div>
</div>
<div class="outter-div">
  <div class="inner-div">
  HELLO WORLD 7
  </div>
</div>
<div class="outter-div">
  <div class="inner-div">
  HELLO WORLD 8
  </div>
</div>
<div class="outter-div">
  <div class="inner-div">
  HELLO WORLD 9
  </div>
</div>
<div class="outter-div">
  <div class="inner-div">
  HELLO WORLD 10
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the problem is the divs are overlapping when height increases. I want the divs below target div to move down not to overlap.

Comment: I see, so I suggest you use http://masonry.desandro.com/ for pinterest-like layout.

Comment: I am trying to avoid any plugins. I am just looking for a better css for this problem.